# Unhandled promise rejection: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I have tried to incorporate the Angular2 quickstart code into my current webpack build and it seems that something is overwriting the `zone.js` promise which is throwing this error. According to most of the stackoverflow posts I've seen, the `zone.js` file needs to be loaded after any files that may include promises.

I'm assuming what is happening is that the html that has the `<src>` tag with the `zone.js` file is getting loaded before webpack loads the rest of the `node_module` files.

Any ideas or suggestions?

---

This is the `package.json` I'm using.

```
{
  "name": "site-pinger",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build:watch": "webpack --colors --progress --watch",
    "build": "webpack --colors --progress",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --hot --inline --port 3000"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "latest",
      "stage-0"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "standard": "^8.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

---

This is the `webpack.config.js` file

```
'use strict'

const webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const devtool = 'source-map'

const devServer = {
  historyApiFallback: true
}

const entry = {
  main: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './src/main'
  ],
}

const output = {
  filename: '[name].js',
  path: __dirname + '/dist',
  publicPath: '/'
}

const extensions = [
  '.js',
  '.ts',
  '.css',
  '.html'
]

const modules = [
  'node_modules',
  'lib'
]

const rules = [{
  test: /.ts$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loaders: ['ts-loader']
}, {
  test: /.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loaders: ['babel-loader']
}, {
  test: /.css$/,
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader' })
}, {
  test: /.html$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  include: /static/,
  loader: 'html-loader'
}, {
  test: /.(ico|png|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
  loader: 'url?limit=10000'
}]

const plugins = [
  new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    hash: true,
    inject: 'head',
    template: 'static/index.html'
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',
    minChunks: Infinity
  })
]

module.exports = {
  devtool,
  devServer,
  entry,
  output,
  resolve: {
    extensions,
    modules
  },
  module: {
    rules
  },
  plugins
}
```

---

This is my index.html where I've manually included the `zone.js` file to ensure that their Promise doesn't get overwritten.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Site Pinger</title>

    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="../src/systemjs.config.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no necessity to load zone.js in separate <script>. It can be included into the bundle. It conflicts with babel-polyfill, which includes core-js Promise polyfill. Why is Systemjs there, isn't it a Webpack question?

Comment: When I left it out of the html, it was throwing errors that it was missing entirely. the Systemjs is there because it was there in the quickstart application on the angular2 github page. I essentially copy-pasted most of their config code and then tried to see if it would work with webpack. I've since just replaced my configuration with [this](https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack) webpack config and project structure and everything seems to be working now. He also seems to include the zone.js file in a different area which i'm not sure why. Not sure if I should delete this post or not.

Comment: Yes, usually polyfills are bundled, and here's the proper order, zone.js follows core-js, https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack/blob/master/src/polyfills.ts

Answer (score 11):

It worked for me when I updated my zone.js package to the latest version by running `npm install zone.js@latest --save`.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar error when loading `core-js` and `zone.js`.
What did the trick for me was to just put the import for `zone.js` after `core-js`.

Changed this:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'core-js';
```

to this:

```
import 'core-js';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

Going back to your webpack problem, as @estus said, there is no need to put  the `systemjs` import there, as it will be included in your `dist/*` files generated by webpack (which are missing in your index.html).

My index.html after "webpacking" my project looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- only some css links here -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>
    </my-app>

    <script src="dist/vendor.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/app.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this bug was making me crazy!

Answer (score 8):

Had same issue. There is import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; in polyfill.ts. I moved it to main.ts and it fixed my issue

Comment: This fixed the issue for my localhost, but not for the live site.

Comment: Try clearing cache

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on old Safari browsers like 10.3 
for me it was just a missing entry in the brrowserslist file.

```
ios_saf >= 10
Safari >= 10
```

[source](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15152#issuecomment-514572736)

Answer (score 0):

SebraGra's answer is correct. However if you're coming here in the context of trying to run Angular inside an asp.net website, in my case version 4.5.2, the error goes away when you render the scripts after the app-root tag. **You will also need to target specifically either es2015 or es5 output in the dist folder**

I haven't yet found a way to dynamically switch it

```
    @{
        Layout = null;
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title></title>
        <base href="/">
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/App-es5")
    </body>
    </html>

    public class AngularBundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/App-es2015")
                .Include(
                    "~/App/dist/App/scripts-es2015*",
                    "~/App/dist/App/vendor-es2015*",
                    "~/App/dist/App/polyfills-es2015*",
                    "~/App/dist/App/runtime-es2015*",
                    "~/App/dist/App/main-es2015*"
                    ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/App-es5")
                .Include(
                    "~/App/dist/App/scripts-es5*",
                    "~/App/dist/App/vendor-es5*",
                    "~/App/dist/App/polyfills-es5*",
                    "~/App/dist/App/runtime-es5*",
                    "~/App/dist/App/main-es5*"
                ));
        }
    }
```

**Update**

I found a way to switch them dynamically by replacing the script tag which means you can target both:

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"module\" src=\"{0}\"></script>", "~/Scripts/App-es2015")
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src=\"{0}\" nomodule defer></script>", "~/Scripts/App-es5")
```

Answer (score 0):

remove import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; from polyfill.ts.

And move it to main.ts.

Clear all of your browser cache before testing.