# Unhandled Promise rejection: `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten

Tags: angular, typescript, polyfills, zone.js

My `polyfills.ts` file contains:

```
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
require('zone.js/dist/zone');
```

Now I am frequently (but not always) getting thiserror:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
>   Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unhandled promise rejection: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise \`(window|global).Promise\` has been overwritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741628/unhandled-promise-rejection-zone-js-has-detected-that-zoneawarepromise-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue have been fixed by https://github.com/angular/zone.js/pull/899, in the next version of `zone.js`(0.8.19), the error will gone.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I fix this?

The code you presented is fine, i.e. the following is the correct order:

```
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
require('zone.js/dist/zone');
```

> Now I am frequently (but not always)

You are probably importing some module *sometimes* that does it in the wrong order.